# How can I make a bar of color go across the screen with text on it?

Tags: html, css

This is my code for my website project. When I execute it, the light blue color bar goes centers on the text, but instead of going horizontally, It goes vertically. I really want it to go horizontal, kind of like a YouTube banner.

This is what it currently looks like: https://gyazo.com/bec50dc13260d0c3b572f55ab0def12c

I don't want it to look this way. I don't want it looking like a tower or a building. I want it to go horizontally, like a floor or ceiling.

```css
        body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }
    
    .jumbotron {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-image: url(image.jpg);
      background-position: 0% 25%;
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 2px;
    }
    
    .navigation {
      background-color: #330;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    }
    
    .navigation a {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .navigation a:hover {
      background-color: #dddddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .navigation a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .intro {
      background-image: url("Engineering.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin: auto;
      z-index: 4;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-size: 100px;
      padding: 10px;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }
    
    .secondbg {
      background-image: url("circuit.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
      align-items: top;
    
    } 
    
    .barofcolour {
      
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      background-position: 0% 25%;
      background-size: ;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 2px;
    }
```

```html
 <body>
      <div class="navigation">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
        <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
        <a href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="#webDev">Web Development</a>
      </div>
    
      <div class="intro">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1>Computer Engineering</h1>
    
        </div>
    
    
      </div>
    
    <div class="secondbg">
      <div class = "barofcolour">
          <div class="courseinfo">
            <h2>About This Course
            </h2>
          </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any help will be appreciated :).

Comment: Why was my question edited? (sorry beginner here))

Comment: why are you using display flex? and you want it to have the same width or just wrap the text

Comment: @JohnBob I edited your question to put your code in snippet:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Comment: @godfather the display flex is for the "Computer Engineering" in title. Not the About This Course.

Comment: ive added what im talking about in the answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i removed display:flex from .secondbg after that there was a margin in h2 and i reduced the font so you can see the difference

```css
h2{
margin:0px;
text-align:center;
}
body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }
    
    .jumbotron {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-image: url(image.jpg);
      background-position: 0% 25%;
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 2px;
    }
    
    .navigation {
      background-color: #330;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    }
    
    .navigation a {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .navigation a:hover {
      background-color: #dddddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .navigation a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .intro {
      background-image: url("Engineering.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin: auto;
      z-index: 4;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-size: 70px;
      padding: 10px;
      line-height: 1.8em;
    }
    
    .secondbg {
      background-image: url("circuit.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center top;
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
    
      align-items: top;
    
    } 
    
    .barofcolour {
      padding:10px;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      background-position: 0% 25%;
      background-size: ;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
      <div class="navigation">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
        <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
        <a href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="#webDev">Web Development</a>
      </div>
    
      <div class="intro">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1>Computer Engineering</h1>
    
        </div>
    
    
      </div>
    
    <div class="secondbg">
      <div class = "barofcolour">
          <div class="courseinfo">
            <h2>About This Course
            </h2>
          </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you have 2 display flex for the . intro and the .secondbg

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it! Do you know how to make the light blue bar thicker though? I kind of want not the same height as the text. https://gyazo.com/0863f4de5b7b29dc49d39f60559c5550

Comment: .barofcolour you do it with padding  or height

Comment: glad that this helped you

Comment: You are a god! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS of your **barofcolour** class, just set the attribute `width:100%`. Should do the trick!

I have added it in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/hrishikeshpaul/pen/WmZKbL)

Hope this answers your problem!

Comment: .barofcolour {
  
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  background-position: 0% 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px;
} This is what I did. You were close, but it just filled the entire bottom of the background. I just want a small-width rectangle of colour behind the text going across the screen. https://gyazo.com/bfc1814f6abbac01255e5f68baf8e413 This is what you solution showed me. I just want a rectangle at the text. Any other ideas?